# custom listview adapter xml cutting off words

Tags: android, android-xml, android-adapter

I created a customlistview adapter with its own xml which is supposed to have a beer style on the left side and then a avg rating on the far right side. My problem is some of the beer styles are a lot of characters long and are cut off:

[image]

currently my xml for the list items is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breweryName"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breweryRate"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want, you just need to wrap_content on the beer name instead of fill_parent to prevent the truncation of the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breweryName"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breweryRate"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you probably want to do is use marquee. I would modify your xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/breweryName"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/breweryRate"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```